# Functional approach to basic array construction

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This is my code, acting upon `myArray`:

```
var myArray = [];
var i;

for(i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
   myArray.push(Math.random());
}
```

Is there a functional equivalent of the above that does without the dummy variable `i`?

*Favorite answers*:

- `while(myArray.push(Math.random()) < 20);`
- `$.map(Array(20), Math.random);`
- `for(var myArray = []; myArray.push(Math.random()) < 20;);`

Comment: I don't think though. You can use "hacks" like `while(myArray.push(Math.random()) < 20);`.

Comment: @FelixKling that does look a lot simpler than the for loop, and it can be debated if its really a hack :)

Comment: @Vatev: Yeah well, it uses side effects which is not considered to be very clean and it's definitely not a functional approach. It's fun though :) Eventually you would put such code in a function anyway...

Comment: @FelixKling: Using a `for`-loop, you could even inline the variable declaration :-)

Comment: Try `Array.from({ length: 20 }, Math.random)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in ES5, there's no real functional equivalent to it, as you have to have something which has an amount of 20 to apply map to...

```
var my20ElementArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var myArray = my20ElementArray.map(Math.random);
```

You could create an [xrange-like function](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2287/) what is in Python but that would just hide this "unused" variable inside a function.

Comment: It's a pity `.map` doesn't handle sparse arrays, otherwise it could be `new Array(20).map(Math.random)`.

Comment: But `jQuery.map` does, just in case the OP is using it. `$.map(new Array(20), Math.random)`

Comment: @pimvdb: See my answer for an (ugly) solution for this

Comment: You can even try `Array.from({ length: 10 }, Math.random)`

Answer (score 3):

With JavaScript 1.7, you can use [Array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Array_comprehensions_(Merge_into_Array_comprehensions)) for this task:

```
var myArray = [Math.random() for each (i in range(0, 20))];
```

---

However, with ES5.1 you can just use the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to generate an array of arbitrary length, and then map it to random numbers. Only drawback is that [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not work with uninitialised values, so I first generate an Array of empty strings by using [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var myArray = new Array(20).join(" ").split(" ").map(Math.random);
```

Ugly, but short. A maybe better (but less understandable) idea from [Creating range in JavaScript - strange syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/1048572):

```
var myArray = Array.apply(null, {length: 20}).map(Math.random);
```

---

Starting with @FelixKlings comment, one could also use this one-liner without the `i` loop variable:

```
for (var myArray=[]; myArray.push(Math.random()) < 20;);
// much better:
for (var myArray=[]; myArray.length < 20;) myArray.push(Math.random());
```

Comment: This will make all of the array elements the same random number.

Comment: I didn't write in array comprehension, as it's an ES.next feature, and I expected the code to be run on today's platform's, but yeah, a nice solution :)

Comment: @AaditMShah: Which one? I don't think so. The [draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:array_comprehensions) reads different, and I've tested the other two.

Comment: @Bergi - My mistake. I expected `Math.random` to be invoked immediately.

Comment: @AaditMShah If the comprehension syntax invoked `Math.random` immediately it would be pretty useless. A "normal" list comprehension would use an expression that refers to the loop variables, in order to compute a different item for each (combination of) loop variables. There's no point adding comprehension syntax to a language if the item expression is evaluated first and then simply repeated.

Comment: Array comprehensions seem not very reusable. They reveal their algorithms pretty much and rather are reminiscent of the imperative style. I wonder why they're considered functional. Why not better a recursive function as `fill = n => ctor => n === 0 ? [] : [new ctor].concat(fill(n - 1)(ctor));`. This works only with constructors though. It would have to be generalized to deal with any type.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: Array comprehensions directly translate to `map`/`concatMap` in functional languages. They're just different syntax.

Comment: Ah, merely syntactic sugar. Now it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something as follows:

```
function makeArray(length, def) {
    var array = [];
    var funct = typeof def === "function";
    while (array.push(funct ? def() : def) < length);
    return array;
}
```

Then you can create arrays as follows:

```
var array = makeArray(100); // an array of 100 elements
var zero = makeArray(5, 0); // an array of 5 `0`s
```

In your case you may do something like:

```
var myArray = makeArray(20, Math.random);
```

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WxtkF/3/

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

it's functionale style and it's very concise.

```
var makeRandomArray = function(n){
    if (n == 0) return [];
    return [Math.random()].concat(makeRandomArray(n-1));
};

console.log(makeRandomArray(20))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YQqGP/

​

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var myArray = String(Array(20)).split(',')
               .map( () => Math.random() );
```

Or extend the Array prototype with something like:

```
Array.prototype.vector = function(n,fn){
  fn = fn || function(){return '0';};
  while (n--){
    this.push(fn());
  }
  return this;
}
// usage
var myArray = [].vector(20, () => Math.random());
```

Or try something funny:

```
var myArray = function a(n,fn){
  return n ? a(n-1,fn).concat(fn()) : [];
}(20, () => Math.random())
```

Or use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (ES>=2015)

```
Array.from({length: 20}).map(() => Math.random())
```