# Why do I get undefined values in my array?

Tags: javascript

Why is the value of

```
(new Array(2)).map(function (x, i, a) { return i })
```

[undefined, undefined] instead of [0, 1]?

Comment: Because `map` does not visit empty indices ("sparse array")

Comment: @Bergi um, make it an answer. lol

Comment: You can use `Array(2).join("|").split("|").map(function (x, i, a) { return i })` or any map implementation that doesn't check if an index actually exists, like `jQuery.map`

Comment: @epascarello: Gonna do it, I was just searching for the related/duplicate question on JS list comprehension.

Comment: Esailija: Interesting but too much of a hack for my taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Array(2)` generates a sparse array - with no values, but of length 2. It is equivalent to [`[,,]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11808946/1048572).

Now, [Array's `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is specified to leave out uninitialised/deleted indices, so you just get back another empty array.

Related question on what you want to do: [How to write List/Array comprehensions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11808758/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

when you specify the size of an javascript array it fills it with undefined values

Comment: No, the point is that is does not fill with values.

Comment: and it will return undefined, thats what i wanted to say