# How to write 'for-in' in JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functional approach to basic array construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808758/functional-approach-to-basic-array-construction)

I am new to js. I just want to know which one is the right approach. Below I have posted my code.

```
var doubles = (i*20 for (i in it));
var doubles ={i*20 for (i in it)};
```

Thanks

Comment: Answer is None. It's not python

Comment: Are you asking about Javascript 1.7? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generator_expressions

Comment: Javascript 1.7+ isn't widely supported. Unless it's for use with nodejs or anything unrelated to the browser. I wouldn't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use ordinary *for* loops when iterating over arrays. *for...in* is used for iterating over object properties.

So, the correct way is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

To iterate over object properties:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
     // do something with prop
}
```

Comment: How do you know `it` is not an object? :-)

Comment: @Bergi you don't really know, an array is an object. So if you pass an array to the `for in` it may iter over indexes and other keys. That said, if you pass an object to a function you should expect and object to be passed to the for. If you don't know what's getting into your function, it's a different story.

Comment: I don't. It was an assumption ;)

Comment: @Davorin ,It is object. Your code solves my problem but I want to know that how to do it in my way if possible. Just curisity!

Comment: @minhaz, I don't think it is possible in pure JS, you should try CoffeeScript if you want to use _comprehensions_.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `it` is an array, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var doubles = it.map(function(i){ return i*20; });
```

Also you might want to have a look at [how to write List/Array comprehensions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11808758/1048572)

---

Assuming you want to use Mozilla's [Generator expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generator_expressions) (where `it` is an existing `Iterator`), you need to use square brackets:

```
var twentyfolds = [i*20 for (i in it)];
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, ECMAScript 6 (aka Harmony) will most likely introduce [a new sane way of iterating over objects (arrays included)](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aiterators):

```
for(var x of array) {
    // do something with x
}
```

It will also introduce [array comprehensions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aarray_comprehensions) and [generator expressions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aarray_comprehensions) to the core language:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log([i*20 for (i of arr)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options are syntax errors. If 'it' is a list, then you can iterate through it with a for loop or the forEach method. In your case however, it looks like you are really looking for the map method.

```
var doubles = it.map(function (i) { return i * 20; });
```