# arithmetic sequence: use apply or map instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, sequence, apply

I have a for loop like so:

```
var myary = [];
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
  myary[i] = i;
}
//yields [0, 1, 2]
```

I'd like to accomplish the same with `myary.apply()` or a functional equivalent, but I am not familiar with generating arithmetic sequences via functional methods in JavaScript.
Is this possible?

Comment: `[].map.call( Array(10)+1, Function.call.bind(Number)  )`

Comment: `Object.keys(Object(Array(10)+0)).map(Number)`

Comment: Check out [Creating range in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/1048572)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Functional approach to basic array construction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11808876/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Any reason you didn't close the question as duplicate ?

Comment: @dystroy: Because it's not an exact duplicate. If you think that's fine, throw your hammer; I wanted to wait for confirmation by jml whether it answered his question.

Comment: @Bergi Hum... right, not exactly a duplicate. I'll let OP (or somebody else decide)

Comment: @Bergi - agreed.  IMO, this is more about generating sequences w/ said approaches, rather than a more general query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no clean and easy functional solution in ES5. Here's the simplest I have:

```
var myary = Array.apply(0,Array(N)).map(function(_,i){return i});
```

Edit: Be careful that expressions of this kind, while being sometimes convenient, can be very slow. [This commit](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/commit/f61e4dc5d6415489469b1252feb1f3d1f9b7abc7) I made was motivated by performance issues. An old style and boring for loop can often be much faster.

Comment: although maybe not "clean" or "easy", I find this to be readable.

Comment: `Function.call.bind(Number)` is a good way to get arguments[1] without a custom...

Comment: @jml Just in case, you might want to check my edit, so that you don't painfully discover later the reason of a slowdown in your application.